# Inspecting django unittest errors in pdb

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing, django-unittest

I have a unittest that throws an exception. The exception isn't thrown by my code, it's from somewhere deep within django. I want to open a pdb session at that spot and see what's the haps, but when I open ipython with pdb and `run test myapp` the test runs, throws the exception, prints it, but pdb doesn't catch anything.

I guess the desperate-man's solution is to open up django's source and insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the spot I want to investigate. But there's gotta be a better way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps using nosetests to run your tests with the --pdb option would work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a breakpoint ( `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` ) at your code and inspect the process? I mean, with the letter 's' you can enter inside a function, so you can go deep until the Django code.

I don't know why you think that using the breakpoint as you say is a bad solution. Actually, that's how I debug all my code.

BTW: Try ipdb insteand pdb. You will love it ;)

Comment: -1 Test runners should provide a post-mortem debugger (i.e., it calls set_trace where an error occurs) so users don't need to do this manually deep inside the interals of massive packages like django